# access workspace in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I have a jenkins pipeline job with the job config pulling Jenkinsfile from  a repo . Once the job runs and pulls the jenkinsfile, it clones the repo and I can see it in workspace icon for the job.

Now when in Jenkinsfile I do cd ${workspace} and ls , it doesnt display anything. How do I access the workspace of the repo of the Jenkinsfile ? Or does it just store the Jenkinsfile itself ?

This is my Jenkinsfile :

```
node ("master"){
    // Mark the code checkout 'Checkout'....
    stage 'Checkout'
    sh "pwd ; ls"
    }
```

As I run it, I get the following log:

```
> GitHub pull request #282 of commit
> 0045a729838aae0738966423ff19c250151ed636, no merge conflicts. Setting
> status of 0045a729838aae0738966423ff19c250151ed636 to PENDING with url
> https://10.146.84.103/job/test1/ and message: 'Pull request builder
> for this security group pr started' Using context: SG Terraform
> Validate/Plan 
>  > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>  > git config remote.origin.url https://github.xxx.net/Terraform/djin-sg/ # timeout=10 Fetching
> upstream changes from https://github.xxx.net/Terraform/djin-sg/
>  > git --version # timeout=10 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials wsjbuild
>  > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.xxx.net/Terraform/djin-sg/
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>  > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10 Checking out Revision 9dd8491b7b18c47eac09cec5a4bff4f16df979bf (origin/master)
>  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>  > git checkout -f 9dd8491b7b18c47eac09cec5a4bff4f16df979bf First time build. Skipping changelog. [Pipeline] node Running on master in
> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test1 [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] stage
> (Checkout) Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is
> deprecated Entering stage Checkout Proceeding [Pipeline] wrap
> [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] sh [test1] Running shell script
> + cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test1
> + ls
```

My question specifically is that to get the Jenkinsfile it clones the djin-sg repo. Its in the workspace as well. So When I do ls why does it show no files ?

As I go to the Jenkins job pipeline steps and open workspace in console I can see the full repo in workspace but I cant seem to access it in the job.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? could you post a minimum, complete, and verifiable (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the form of a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: @burnettk - please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `checkout scm` to actually checkout a repository to the workspace or you can find it under `../${env.JOB_NAME}@script` only on master.
It's better to always checkout `checkout scm` manually because slaves do not have `../$env.JOB_NAME@script` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Try instead a Jenkins pipeline syntax, like:

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'master' } } 
    stages {
        stage('After Checkout') {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd; ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
```